# Manipulate permalinks in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, multisite

first of all. I know i should have some code you can see, but I have no idea what to do.
Is the following possible?
I want to add the word "layout" to my multisite subpages
My site goes like this
example.com/
example.com/services
example.com/layouts
example.com/about
example.com/contact
I have 3 layouts right now (more to come) - All the layouts are multisite subpages
example.com/first-layout
example.com/second-layout
example.com/third-layout
Is i possible to add "layout" before?
Ex. example.com/layout/first-layout
if people go to example.com/layout" they will be redirected to "example.com/layouts"
I don't have any code on this, but i've tried changing the link structure from the multisite settings in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your installation, I think your best bet is to install the plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

The basic idea is that it allows you to set path prefixes, like you are trying to do, inside of WordPress' backend. The alternative is figuring out which server you're using (likely either Apache or nginx) and hard coding some custom rules into the server itself.

Comment: Awesome! I'll try that and come back to you so we know if it works or not :)

Comment: Normally i'll never use plug as the solution but in this case it's really handy... I found this: https://permalinkmanager.pro/?utm_source=wordpress which can do some more stuff also with permalinks.... Thanks for changing my mind so that i could find the right thing :)